ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : pass in an int array to controller method
I'm aware this has been asked elsewhere, but a lot of the questions are very old and stale and .NET has moved on a bit since then so I'm hopeful there is now a simple solution to this other than having to implement a custom model binder...
I have a Web API controller method like this:
[HttpGet("{storeId:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int storeId, int requiredQuantity, [FromQuery] int[] plus)
{
    try
    {
        // lots of incredible things

        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new { message = "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later." });
    }
}

I can invoke this like this:
GET https://localhost:44385/test/test/650?plus=13&plus=4412&plus=4099&requiredQuantity=41

However I need to be able to invoke it like that:
GET https://localhost:44385/test/test/650?plus=13,4412,4099&requiredQuantity=41

Is this possible in a close to native way without having to write a full custom model binder, or pass in a string and convert to an int array?

You could implement custom modelbinder to achieve.
    public class CommaSeparatedBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var stringArray = valueProviderResult.FirstValue?.Split(',')?? Array.Empty<string>();
            int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, s => int.TryParse(s, out int result) ? result : 0);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(intArray);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

Then add this custom binder
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int storeId, int requiredQuantity, [FromQuery][ModelBinder(typeof(CommaSeparatedBinder))] int[] plus)

Test result


I'm not sure of a more native than using model binding but you could make use of an hack, You can use the [FromQuery] attribute with a simple string parameter and handle the conversion inline in your method.
    [HttpGet("{storeId:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int storeId, int requiredQuantity, [FromQuery(Name = "plus")] string plus)
    {
        try
        {
            var plusArray = plus?.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<int>();
            return Ok(plusArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, new { message = "An error occurred. Please try again later." });
        }
    }



Hi Kent, I implemented this approach first but it was decided that it was abit of a smell as the swagger definition was showing a string rather than an array of ints. This might work for some people though so thanks for documenting the alternative approach
